# how to pass an id from javascript to bootstrap model in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I pass a value id to the javascript function.here id is printing.

```
<script>
  function openModal(id) {
    document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
    var img_id = id;
    document.getElementById('caption').innerHTML = img_id;
  }
</script>
```

now i want to pass this value to the bootstrap modal

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <button type="button" id="close"  onclick="closeModal()">close</button>

  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="mySlides">

    <?php    

    //here i want to use this id with if condition so that desired image is 
    //displayed.With for each all images are coming.
    //$project_images = explode(",", $value['project_gallery']);

    $project_images =  json_decode($value['project_gallery'],true); 

    foreach ($project_images as $project_image_value) {
    ?> 

    <img src="<?= base_url() ?>assets/uploads/projects/<? =$project_image_value['fname']?>" style="width:100%">

    <?php
    }
    ?>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

is it possible .if so let me know.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: i want to pass img_id from javascript function to bootstrap model so that i will  use in model

Comment: Where exactly do you want that id to be in model?

Comment: i want to use that id in php code written in modal

Answer (score 0):

Add one hidden field in bootstrap modal like

```
<input type="hidden" id="img_id" name="img_id">
```

and add script

```
function openModal(id) {
$("#img_id").val(id);
document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
var img_id = id;
document.getElementById('caption').innerHTML = img_id;
```

}

So in model you get one field img_id with value that you want to passed

Comment: How can I grab the value of input hidden using php to use

Comment: You have to use GET/POST to send js variable to php

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you elaborate